# Distribution on nodes

Tags: nodes, cockroachdb

I started a CockroachDb in a SIngel cluster with 5 nodes and try to store a table on 3 Specific Nodes. Unfortunately it does not work. Since someone has experience with this

ALTER TABLE belegdaten CONFIGURE ZONE USING
num_replicas = 3,
constraints = '[+ 1, + 2, + 3, - 4, - 5]';

Comment: Looks like there is no such syntax to achieve what you are looking for. It only allows you to specify which region/zone to locate the replicas. See : https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v22.2/configure-replication-zones#types-of-constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CockroachDB doesn't distribute data like what you are trying to do.

To do something like what you want, you can set up your cluster as a multiregion cluster and use regional tables and [data domiciling](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v23.1/data-domiciling). You'd make the 3 nodes a particular region, then set the locality of the tables you want to the same region. In this scenario, you'd really want a six node cluster with 2 regions each with 3 nodes.

But I'm confused about the use-case here. Why is it important for the tables to be replicated to 3 and only 3 nodes in the cluster? What is the purpose of the other 2 nodes? With CockroachDB you can connect to any node and retrieve the data, even if it's not a replica of the range.